# how to force blender freestyle engine to redraw the same frame different

Tags: freestyle

*anwesered* I have been trying to make a freestyle line changing each frame even though it's the same. I've been wanting a sketchy look for a while and cant find anything
help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add freestyle modifiers on your lineSet and animate differents settings with a driver depending on the current frame. The only one acting like you want by default is the spatial noise in the geometry tab.

The is an exemple of what you can achieve by mixing and animating differents setting like thickness noise and texture offset

[image]

[image]